# How can we auto resize the size of components in SWT?

Tags: java, layout, resize, swt

In my SWT application i have certain components inside the SWT shell.

Now how can i auto re-size this components according to the size of display window.

```
Display display = new Display();

Shell shell = new Shell(display);
Group outerGroup,lowerGroup;
Text text;

public test1() {
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns=1;
    shell.setLayout(gridLayout);

    outerGroup = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);

    GridData data = new GridData(1000,400);
    data.verticalSpan = 2;
    outerGroup.setLayoutData(data);    

    gridLayout = new GridLayout();

    gridLayout.numColumns=2;
    gridLayout.makeColumnsEqualWidth=true;
    outerGroup.setLayout(gridLayout);

    ...
}
```

i.e when I decrease the size of window the components inside it should appear according to that.

Comment: You can listen for `SWT.Resize` event and call the `layout()` on the components

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That sounds suspiciously like you aren't using layouts.

The whole concept of layouts makes worrying about resizing needless. The layout will take care of the size of all of its components.

**I would recommend to read the [Eclipse article about layouts](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html)**

Your code can easily be corrected. Don't set the size of individual components, the layout will determine their size. If you want the window to have a predefined size, set the shell's size:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Group outerGroup = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);

    // Tell the group to stretch in all directions
    outerGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    outerGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
    outerGroup.setText("Group");

    Button left = new Button(outerGroup, SWT.PUSH);
    left.setText("Left");

    // Tell the button to stretch in all directions
    left.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Button right = new Button(outerGroup, SWT.PUSH);
    right.setText("Right");

    // Tell the button to stretch in all directions
    right.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    shell.setSize(1000,400);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Before resizing:

[image: Before resizing]

After resizing:

[image: After resizing]

Comment: What if I want the initial size of the dialog/shell to be the size of its contents? I mean, there is a minimal size for the buttons, depending on their content too, so how can I set their container to be the size of them? This is useful in case of various languages translations (German is probably longer than Chinese/Japanese, for example).

Comment: @androiddeveloper call `pack()` on their parent or even the `Shell`.

Comment: @Baz Seems to work, but doesn't work well for "FormLayout". Maybe because I've (out of laziness) used absoutlute positions. Also, for some reason, when I try to create a new Shell that's inside the main one, and make it center (like here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DialogShell.htm ) , it doesn't seem to position it correctly. Do you know why?

Comment: @androiddeveloper This won't work with absolute positions. That's why you shouldn't use them. Can't help you with the other problem without details. Maybe worth posting a new question?