# SWT GUI is resizing according to display

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

We have created one SWT GUI and added few components in absolute layout.
we designed this UI on my desktop but whenever I opened it on my laptop I can see
some scattered UI.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at using non-absolute layouts. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928741/how-can-we-auto-resize-the-size-of-components-in-swt/12929757. Also this: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html

Comment: If you mean the code is using `setBounds` everywhere this is never a good choice for all sorts of reasons.